# Blinking Custom Markers In Google maps iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have placed 6 custom markers with the same coordinates in google maps iOS SDK. Those markers are continuously blinking/Toggling. I don't want blinking animation at all. Please help me.

Here is my Source Code.

```
-(void)loadPlacesInMapWithIndex:(int)index{

    for (int i = 0; i < [[[SearchManager sharedInstance]searchedStallArray] count]; i++) {
        Stall *stall = [[[SearchManager sharedInstance]searchedStallArray] objectAtIndex:i];

        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([stall.stallLatitude doubleValue],[stall.stallLongitude doubleValue]);
        marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.44f, -0.07f);
        marker.userData = stall;
        marker.tappable = YES;
        self.infoView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"StallInfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        marker.iconView = self.infoView;
        if (index == i) {
            [self.infoView.stallPinImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RateLabel.png"]];
            [self.infoView.stallPriceLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

            CGFloat currentZoom = self.stallsMapView.camera.zoom;
            [CATransaction begin];
            [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.5f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
            [self.stallsMapView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition
                                                          cameraWithLatitude:[stall.stallLatitude doubleValue]
                                                          longitude:[stall.stallLongitude doubleValue]
                                                          zoom:currentZoom]];
            [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            }];
            [CATransaction commit];

        }else{
            [self.infoView.stallPinImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"horse.png"]];
            [self.infoView.stallPriceLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        }

        self.infoView.stallPriceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",stall.stallPrice];

        marker.map = self.stallsMapView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: Which version of Google Maps SDK are you using?

Comment: Some body please help me. I'm waiting for the solution.

Comment: which pod are you using ? and pl. post image(gif) for blinking animation.

Comment: post your blinking image pic ..

Comment: Is it possible that you are removing markers and recreating them again all the time? Could you try to put a breakpoint in that method to see how many times are you using it?

Answer (score 15):

You have to provide them diffrent **zIndex** property. This property defines which marker is on the top of stack. The highest numbers are on top.

For your code, insert under:

```
 marker.tappable = YES;
```

this line of code:

```
 marker.zIndex = (UInt32)i
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to setup the [zIndex property of the markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_overlay#a0e9871b40c30bb39f9a45dadaf7a0f75)? Probably the markers blink because they're overlapping an there is no clear draw ordering.

Comment: I haven't. Could you please give me an example with Source code.

Comment: I have tried this blinking issue get resolved by adding zIndex property.